# How to group the array based on another array value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can i aggregate group this "events.text" based on the "events.parse_data.intent.confidence" is 0. The below screenshot is my collection format.[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKAkq.jpg

Comment: What you want to do is group the events' array using events.text as _id where events.parse_data.intent.confidence matches 0?

Comment: i want to know the only events.text values where events.parse_data.intent.confidence matches 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try unwinding the array of events to work as each was a single document:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$events"}, {$match: {"events.parse_data.intent.confidence": 0}}, {$project: {text: "$events.text", _id: 0}}]);
```

Comment: its works fine but as one value per one document.how can i group this as a single document.

Comment: Please edit your question showing the expected result.